# Curl coudn't resolve proxy 'PUT'

Tags: curl, put, riak

I'm trying to add a link to a already existing bucket in RIAK which was created by me before using POST , and now im getting the following error.

```
curl -x PUT http://localhost:8091/riak/games/fallout4 -H 'Content-type: image/jpeg" -H "Link:</riak/photos/vaultboy.jpeg>;riaktag=\"photo\"" --data-binary @vaultboy.jpeg

curl:(5)Couldn't resolve proxy 'PUT'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a `-X` uppercase, not `-x` lowercase, so :

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8091/riak/games/fallout4 -H 'Content-type: image/jpeg" -H "Link:</riak/photos/vaultboy.jpeg>;riaktag=\"photo\"" --data-binary @vaultboy.jpeg
```

or as @Daniel Stenberg stated in comments :

```
curl http://localhost:8091/riak/games/fallout4 -H 'Content-type: image/jpeg" -H 'Link:</riak/photos/vaultboy.jpeg>;riaktag="photo"' -T vaultboy.jpeg
```

From

```
man curl | less +/--upload-file
```

:

> -T, --upload-file
>
> This transfers the specified local file to the remote URL. If there is no file part in the specified URL, curl  will  append
>   the local file name. NOTE that you must use a trailing / on the last directory to really prove to Curl that there is no file
>   name or curl will think that your last directory name is the remote file name to use. That will most likely cause the upload
>   operation to fail. **If this is used on an HTTP(S) server, the PUT command will be used.**

Comment: Since -X shouldn't be used for methods curl already supports, a better version of that command line would be: `curl http://localhost:8091/riak/games/fallout4 -H 'Content-type: image/jpeg" -H "Link:</riak/photos/vaultboy.jpeg>;riaktag=\"photo\"" -T vaultboy.jpeg`